# Plots coming out empty with pandas.plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to plot a df that must have two y-axes. I can get the plot to work using only one axis, but when I use two it comes out empty. I've tried separating into two separate dataframes and equally not doing this but neither is working.

My code currently:

```
    df1 = A dataframe with two columns of data and a period index.
    df2 = A dataframe with one column of data and a period index, to 
    plot on a separate axis .

    colors = ['b', 'g']            
    styles = ['-', '-']
    linewidths = [4,2]

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for col, style, lw, color in zip(df1.columns, styles, linewidths, colors):
        df1[col].plot(style=style, color=color, lw=lw, ax=ax)

    plt.xlabel('Date')

    plt.ylabel('First y axis label')
    plt.hold()

    colors2 = ['b']
    styles2 = ['-']
    fig2, ax2 = plt.subplots()

    for col, style, lw, color in zip(df2.columns, styles, linewidths, colors):
        df2.monthly_windspeed_to_plot[col].plot(style=style, color=color, lw=lw, ax=ax)
    plt.ylabel('Second y axis label')

    plt.title('A Title')
    plt.legend(['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'], loc='upper center',
                bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.05))

    plt.savefig("My title.png")
```

The result of this is an empty plot.

What is the mistake in my code?

Comment: Please don't give us the full code, reduce it to a minimal example we can reproduce.

Comment: Apologies. Now Edited.

Comment: Give us also fake data so we can reproduce the problem quickly. And make sure that every line you wrote is useful to us. (eg. is `colors = ['b', 'g']` useful for us ? ) In addition, you might find the issue yourself by doing so.

Comment: At first glance, it looks like you're explicitly plotting them both on the same axes.  (Note that you have `ax=ax` in both calls, while you've called the second axes `ax2`.)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're explicitly plotting them both on the same axes.  You've made a new figure and a second axes called `ax2`, but you're plotting the second dataframe on the first axes by calling `df2.plot(..., ax=ax)` instead of `df2.plot(..., ax=ax2)`

As a simplified example, you're basically doing:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some placeholder data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df1.plot(ax=ax)

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()
df2.plot(ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

When you want something more like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate some placeholder data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(10))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df1.plot(ax=ax)

fig, ax2 = plt.subplots()
df2.plot(ax=ax2) # Note that I'm specifying the new axes object

plt.show()
```